# Is 'dialog' role the right choice for the popup?

Tags: html, dialog, accessibility, roles

[WAI reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#dialog), [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_dialog_role).

WAI says:

> A dialog is an **application window** that is designed to interrupt the
>   current processing of an application in order to **prompt** the user to
>   enter information or **require a response**.

As I understood, dialog is shown to ask some information to proceed. Its purpose is not to show a separate section. So it applicable in case when a dialog contains 'yes/no', 'proceed' buttons. Or when forms exists.

MDN says:

> The dialog role is used to **mark up** a DHTML based application dialog or window that **separates** content or UI from the **rest** of the web application or page. Visually, dialogs are generally placed on top of the rest of the page content using an overlay.

What I have got from this quote, you could use dialog for ordinary popups.

Furthermore, [Bootstrap4](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/) also thinks like MDN.

Who is right? What is the real purpose `dialog` role and what role should be used for simple popups (separated sections) (maybe 'document')?

Comment: 'require a response' can mean any form of interaction, including forcing the user to close it by clicking a 'cancel' button or an 'X' icon in order to access the page. It's not just for buttons or forms.  Clicking on the 'close' button is still a response. Even if you're not trying to prompt the user to enter information, you are still requiring a response by obstructing the underlaying content before forcing them to close the dialog to proceed.

Comment: Check the pattern from the W3C. In a rush, cannot offer more now. https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/#alertdialog

Comment: @Skerrvy I think it is not an eligible example. It is the same as to show browser window to close it (as it has 'close' button). The main poin in a popup is a content, which is separated from the main document

Comment: for more info, check out this free egghead.io course on accessible modal dialogs from Marcy Sutton: https://egghead.io/lessons/html-5-accessible-modal-dialogs

Comment: If you're just looking for what is the correct definition, check the W3C like @aardrian mentioned. His link points to the alert dialog, this link is for the dialog: https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/#dialog_modal

Comment: @Skerrvy thanks for the 'egghead' link. It is very useful. As about aria practices, I have seen it before. I does duplicates dialog role definition from the wai aria specification and also contains notices how it should be implemented. However, it does not lay any light on the discussing topic.

Comment: @Skerrvy I also have seen alertdialog role some time after the question publishing. What I found, it is very close to the dialog by the definion.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I think so that dialog as the role is a better choice for the popup window. but also be beware the semantics of the contents inside the dialog changes like for instance you cannot use navigation keys for reading the contents inside the dialog instead you have to press the key Insert + Space (Am a desktop user.) this is for NVDA other screen readers like JAWS and Voice Over will read fine I guess without having to press any special keys.

Comment: I do not understand. If I implement `dialog` element as WAI says then I need to manage a focus via js and keep it in a dialog.

Comment: Yes but try putting a table inside this dialog the nvda does not read this unless the key I mentioned is pressed as the navigation controls don't work inside the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware also that the [`<dialog>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog) may be a better choice rather than `<div role="dialog">`.

> The HTML `<dialog>` element represents a dialog box or other interactive component, such as an inspector or window.

Please note its current [poor browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=dialog).